# matlab: from 'load' commend to vector

Tags: matlab, time-series

How can I get a vector from a file: list.mat?

I wrote:

```
temp=load('list.mat');
```

'temp' is now a '1x1 struct', but when I'm double clicking on 'list.mat' (at Current Folder window) it says it is '1x1 double timeseries'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be knowing the format of structure, how to access structure to get what you want. Check the below demo on the same, which would be useful for you.

In the below example I am making signal/ time series a structure and extracting the same from the structure.

```
%% Make a time series a structure 
t = 0:1:60 ;
amp = rand(size(t)) ;
signal = [t' amp'] ;
temp = struct ;
temp.signal = signal ;
%% Extract time series from structure
signal = temp.signal ;
t = signal(:,1) ;
amp = signal(:,2) ;
```

Comment: If I got what you have written as a 'mat' file, and now wishing to load it:  dataload=load('data.mat'); after load commend I can get a matrix by: newData=dataload.signal;?

Comment: Thanks a lot to you, I have never used struct on 'matlab' but your example made it clear!!